# Flatten list to R dataframe

Tags: r, rblpapi

I have a nested list that I want to convert to a dataframe using R, similar to this question [flatten a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467321/flatten-a-data-frame)

Here is the structure of my list

```
> str(rf_curves$GBP)
List of 27
 $ NA                  :'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date   :Class 'Date'  int(0) 
  ..$ px_last: num(0) 
 $ BP0012M       Index :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date   : Date[1:5], format: "2018-05-21" "2018-05-22" ...
  ..$ px_last: num [1:5] 0.929 0.931 0.918 0.918 0.901
 $ BP0003M       Index :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date   : Date[1:5], format: "2018-05-21" "2018-05-22" ...
  ..$ px_last: num [1:5] 0.623 0.623 0.619 0.614 0.611
 $ BP0006M       Index :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date   : Date[1:5], format: "2018-05-21" "2018-05-22" ...
  ..$ px_last: num [1:5] 0.746 0.743 0.734 0.733 0.723
 $ NA                  :'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ date   :Class 'Date'  int(0) 
  ..$ px_last: num(0)
```

I would like a dataframe with

- *date* on the rows
- the *ticker*  on the columns (BP0012M and BP0003M are example of *tickers*)
- cells populated with `px_last`.

So a sample of the dataframe would be:

```
date           NA   BP0012M BP0003M BOP0006M
2018-05-21          0.929   0.623   0.746
2018-05-22          0.931   0.623   0.743
2018-05-23          0.918   0.619   0.743
2018-05-24          0.918   0.614   0.733
2018-05-25          0.901   0.611   0.723
```

The final goal is to have a convinient way to get the risk-free curve given a particular start date. For example BP0012M is the 12 month GBP libor. I currently load data from bloomberg, using library(Rblpapi). If I can get the same data from another provider e.g. Quandl that is ok. If I can achieve this goal, without flatten the list to a dataframe, I'm fine with that solution too.

---

Edit: Requested output is pasted below

```
> dput(rf_curves$GBP)
structure(list(`NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `BP0012M       Index` = structure(list(
    date = structure(17672:17676, class = "Date"), px_last = c(0.92894, 
    0.93081, 0.91831, 0.9182, 0.90056)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 5L)), `BP0003M       Index` = structure(list(
    date = structure(17672:17676, class = "Date"), px_last = c(0.62281, 
    0.6225, 0.619, 0.61406, 0.61067)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 5L)), `BP0006M       Index` = structure(list(
    date = structure(17672:17676, class = "Date"), px_last = c(0.7463, 
    0.74323, 0.73411, 0.73321, 0.72312)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 5L)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `BPSW30   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.758, 1.768, 
    1.715, 1.696, 1.628, 1.531, 1.56725)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `BPSW8    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.5675, 1.5955, 
    1.5375, 1.5175, 1.4475, 1.342, 1.37775)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW1F   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(0.942, 0.9575, 
    0.9225, 0.9188, 0.8864, 0.84505, 0.863)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW9    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.6115, 1.6395, 
    1.5795, 1.5585, 1.4885, 1.381, 1.419)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW2    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17679L, 17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.0335, 
    1.0508, 1.0094, 0.9988, 0.9674, 0.9674, 0.9027, 0.92975)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 8L)), `BPSW10   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17679L, 17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.651, 
    1.675, 1.616, 1.593, 1.52, 1.52, 1.427, 1.455)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 8L)), `NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `BPSW3    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.1795, 1.2025, 
    1.1525, 1.1445, 1.0965, 1.01, 1.0435)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW12   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.7105, 1.7325, 
    1.6735, 1.6495, 1.5795, 1.474, 1.5115)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW4    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.294, 1.33, 
    1.27, 1.258, 1.202, 1.107, 1.1371)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW15   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.7615, 1.7805, 
    1.7225, 1.6985, 1.6295, 1.525, 1.5615)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW5    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.3855, 1.4155, 
    1.3595, 1.3465, 1.2875, 1.185, 1.21425)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW20   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.7895, 1.8045, 
    1.7485, 1.7255, 1.6565, 1.554, 1.5895)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW6    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.4565, 1.4855, 
    1.4285, 1.4135, 1.35725, 1.2555, 1.278)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW25   CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.778, 1.791, 
    1.737, 1.716, 1.647, 1.548, 1.5835)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L)), `BPSW7    CMPN Curncy` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(17672L, 17673L, 17674L, 17675L, 17676L, 
    17680L, 17681L), class = "Date"), px_last = c(1.5155, 1.5445, 
    1.4875, 1.4695, 1.4025, 1.298, 1.331)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = c(NA, 7L))), .Names = c("NA", "BP0012M       Index", 
"BP0003M       Index", "BP0006M       Index", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "BPSW30   CMPN Curncy", "NA", "NA", "BPSW8    CMPN Curncy", 
"BPSW1F   CMPN Curncy", "BPSW9    CMPN Curncy", "BPSW2    CMPN Curncy", 
"BPSW10   CMPN Curncy", "NA", "BPSW3    CMPN Curncy", "BPSW12   CMPN Curncy", 
"BPSW4    CMPN Curncy", "BPSW15   CMPN Curncy", "BPSW5    CMPN Curncy", 
"BPSW20   CMPN Curncy", "BPSW6    CMPN Curncy", "BPSW25   CMPN Curncy", 
"BPSW7    CMPN Curncy"))
```

Comment: Can you share the output from `dput(rf_curves$GBP)`?

Comment: > dput(rf_curves$GBP)
structure(list(`NA` = structure(list(date = structure(integer(0), class = "Date"), 
    px_last = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"px_last"), row.names = integer(0)), `BP0012M       Index` = structure(list(
    date = structure(17672:17676, class = "Date"), px_last = c(0.92894, 

and so on but I reach the character limit, see full output at paste.ofcode.org and paste in the URL cdP8xak6yuKFQ5V65zgssb

Comment: Please amend your question to include the output from `dput(rf_curves$GBP)`, instead of pasting it in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to row-bind the dataset, then use `tidyr::spread`. Suppose your list of dataframes is `dat`, then

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- bind_rows(dat, .id = "ticker") %>%
  mutate(ticker = gsub("^([A-Z0-9]+).*$", "\\1", ticker)) %>%
  spread(key = ticker, value = px_last)
```

where the `gsub` cleans up`ticker` to include only the ticker itself. The output looks like

```
out[, 1:6]
#         date BP0003M BP0006M BP0012M BPSW10 BPSW12
# 1 2018-05-21 0.62281 0.74630 0.92894  1.651 1.7105
# 2 2018-05-22 0.62250 0.74323 0.93081  1.675 1.7325
# 3 2018-05-23 0.61900 0.73411 0.91831  1.616 1.6735
# 4 2018-05-24 0.61406 0.73321 0.91820  1.593 1.6495
# 5 2018-05-25 0.61067 0.72312 0.90056  1.520 1.5795
# 6 2018-05-28      NA      NA      NA  1.520     NA
# 7 2018-05-29      NA      NA      NA  1.427 1.4740
# 8 2018-05-30      NA      NA      NA  1.455 1.5115
```

Comment: Works! Does the `\\1` select the first row (i.e. the names)? I don't understand the gsub part and how you can first use the id "ticker" and then after that create the variable using mutate?

Comment: Every ticker represent a time to maturity (TTM). For BP0003M the TTM is 3/12. For BP0012M the TTM is 1. For BPSW10 the TTM is 10. For BPSW12 the TTM is 12. Later I will have to **interpolate** between for example 4y and 5y TTM. So: Can I rename the columns and then re-arrange them in order of TTM so that it's easier to interpolate later?

Comment: If you have follow-up questions, I would suggest opening new questions for them. The comments section is not a good place to provide answers. Furthermore, opening new questions would allow others who have the same questions to find the solutions.